# ReactJS populating fields during componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a grip on how ReactJS populates variables.  I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Home extends React.Component {

appFields = {
    title: '',
    description: ''
}

componentWillMount() {

    function valuesToArray(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
    }

    //populate the state in case the fetch failes for some reason
    let defaultTitle = "Default Title";
    let defaultDescription = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.";

    this.appFields.title = defaultTitle;
    this.appFields.description = defaultDescription;

    //Make use of the API not the web service.  This should return 2 pieces of data
    let url = "http://wmjwwebapi-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/homepage";
    const options = { method: 'GET' };

    fetch(url, options)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        if (myJson == undefined) 
        {
            console.log("fetch failed");
        } 
        else 
        {
            //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned
            var newArray = [];
            newArray = valuesToArray(myJson);  
            console.log("returned title: ", newArray[0].product_title);
            console.log("returned description: ", newArray[0].product_description);

            this.appFields.title = newArray[0].product_title;
            this.appFields.description = newArray[0].product_description;
        }
    });   
}

render() {

        const appTitle = this.appFields.title;
        const appDesc = this.appFields.description;
        return (              
            <div>
                <div id="appTitle">
                    <center>{ appTitle }</center>
                </div>
                <div id="appDescription">
                    { appDesc }
                </div>
                <div>
                <button id="btnStartScan"
                    type='button'     
                    onClick={() => { 
                        location.href = ('/landingpage') 
                    }}>
                    Let's Go!
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

    );
}
}

export default Home
```

What I am trying to do is have the componentWillMount() function populate the values of appFields.title and appFields.description so I can render some  elements and have the values of appFields.title and appFields.description displayed.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger rerender in react easily is to change state. Right now you have created your own state (that object `appFields`) which is not react valid state.

Just rename it to `state` and when you recieve data in `componentDidMount` use `this.setState({ data })`. The react will render it automatically.

EDIT: 
as stated by @azium change also change `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`

Comment: also change `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`

Comment: Yes, `componentWillMount` will be depricated (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount). Thanks for noticing :) @azium

Comment: I added     State = {
        title: '',
        description: ''
    }     
        before the componentDidMount() and changed Did to Will.  I also changed all references from this.appFields to this.state.  and to update the two state fields, I use this.setState({ title: newArray[0].product_title }); and this.setState({ description: newArray[0].product_description });.  Now, when the app runs, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null on the line right after the render() {.  Its on the line const appTitle=this.state.title

Comment: for more information about state and lifecycle please read [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) @JonathanSmall